# How to update/write a dataframe into an excel file located in S3 bucket

Tags: excel, python-3.x, amazon-s3, databricks

I have a process where I open an excel file, select a certain cell range and write my data frame in there. The excel file is in my local machine and I can use

```
 openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
```

or

```
pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='openpyxl')
```

for my purpose. It works fine. Now I want to automate this process and store my excel file in s3. But I dont think openpyxl can work with s3.

Is there any alternative way to implement this concept of opening an excel file, reading its cell range and updating the file while its stored in s3 ?

Answer (score 0):

1.)Do all your processing on the excel file in your local machine.

2.)Write a function in your code to pick this excel file and upload it on the appropriate path on s3.

You can use [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) for uploading file on s3.

Comment: the process is such that I have to store the file somewhere else rather than local machine. Be it cloud storage or whatever.

Comment: If you are using a cloud storage like `ec2`, process the excel on that `ec2` machine. Configure `aws` on this machine. Use `boto3` to upload to s3.